# How to get a HTML element by text using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm encoutered a problem that is could not get a HTML element by element's text.My HTML looks like:

```
...
<table>
  ...
  <tr>
    ...
    <td class="oMain">test value</td>
    ...
  <tr>
  ...
</table>
...
```

For some special reasons,I have to get the '<td class="oMain">' element using it's text 'test value'. I tried '//tr[td='test value']/td' but no result.How can i write the XPath expression?

Any help is welcome.Thanks!

Comment: I'm using htmlcleaner to parsing in java,and i need only xpath expression rather than progamming. BTW,is '//td.oMain' Xpath specification compliance?

Comment: the <tr> doesn't have a closing </tr>

Answer (score 2):

In the xpath expression, first put the element node, which in your case is td, and then apply the filter text()='text node'

//td[text()='test value']

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression

```
//tr[td='test value']/td
```

places the predicate on the parent node "tr". Maybe that's what's causing the problem.

What you want probably is this

```
//td[@class = "oMain" and child::text() = 'test value']]
```

---

Here's a link to th W3 specification of the xPath language for further reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression seems to be correct. Do you have a default namespace (e.g. XHTML) in your html? If so, you can modify your XPath like this:

```
//*[local-name()='td' and text()='test value']
```

If you can figure out how to use namespaces, you could also do

```
//xhtml:tr[xhtml:td='test value']/xhtml:td
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to do the parsing? In Ruby + Hpricot, you can do

```
doc.search("//td.oMain").each do |cell|
  if cell.inner_html == "test value"
    return cell
  end
end
```

In this case, cell would be:

```
<td class="oMain">test value</td>
```